# EXCEL VBA - How to find the same number, in different formats, using .FIND

Tags: excel, find, format, vba

This code comes from another post I had help with...
1) [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536810/execute-a-subroutine-when-a-user-enters-a-trigger-into-a-cell)
2)  [Second edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424585/error-capture-while-using-find-is-not-identifing-error)

A new problem I've found is that .FIND does not find 9,100 when searching for 9100, due to different number formats, e.g. Number vs General.

I tried a couple of things, that busted the code.  Seems simple, but I'm not finding an answer online.

1) How can I make it find the same number in a format?

Summary of what the code does:
When triggered by entering a "y" in col G, the code will retrieve the value on the same row in either col d or E.  Then it will search col K for the same value and if found, make that cell the active cell.

This is the basic working code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rgG As Range
Dim rgK As Range
Dim cSearch As Range
Dim lLoop As Long
Dim cResult As Range
Dim rgXsct As Range

'Find the last used rows in Cols G & K
Dim lrowG As Long
Dim lrowK As Long

lrowG = Columns("G:G").Find(What:="*", _
             After:=Range("G1"), _
             LookAt:=xlPart, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             MatchCase:=False).Row
'Debug.Print lrowG

lrowK = Columns("K:K").Find(What:="*", _
             After:=Range("K1"), _
             LookAt:=xlPart, _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
             MatchCase:=False).Row
'Debug.Print lrowK

Set rgG = Range("g5:g" & lrowG)
Set rgK = Range("k6:k" & lrowK)
Set rgXsct = Intersect(Target, rgG)  '"Intersect" will ensure the current cell lies on the correct column.

'*********** IF CONDITIONS to run. ****************
'1) Columns.count & Row.count = 1 confirms only one cell selected (not a range of cells). -- I think
'2) LCase(Target.Text) = "y" makes the Target lowcase and compares it.
'3) Intersect makes sure the Target is in the relevant range.
'4)

If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And _
  LCase(Target.Text) = "y" And _
  Not rgXsct Is Nothing Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set cSearch = Target.Offset(0, -3)            'Returns value in Col D
    If cSearch = 0 Or cSearch = "" Then Set cSearch = Target.Offset(0,     -2)  'If nothing in D, check E.
        If cSearch = 0 Or cSearch = "" Then GoTo end_search     'If nothing in E, end.
'Debug.Print "Target "; Target
'Debug.Print "cSearch.value "; cSearch.Value
'This will loop through the column to search, to find the value identified above, and return its cell address.
        With rgK
            Set cResult = .Cells(1, 1)
            'For lLoop = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, cSearch.Value)
            Set cResult = .Find(What:=cSearch.Value, _
                   After:=cResult, _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False)
'Debug.Print "cResult " & cResult
            If Not cResult Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "val: " & cSearch.Value & "   Matching Cell: " & cResult.Address
'Use the cell address identified above to move the active cell to that address.
                Cells(Range(cResult.Address).Row,    Range(cResult.Address).Column).Select     'Have to convert the address to row/column to use in Cell.Select.
            Else
                MsgBox (cSearch.Value & " not found.")
                GoTo end_search
            End If
            'Next lLoop
        End With
End If
end_search:
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End Sub
```

2) Can you tell me the value of that commented out `For` loop after the `with`?  It was suggested as a solution to make this overall code work, but it works without it.

3) How can I make this more concise? It seems complex.  For instance, why do I need a `with` statement, when `Columns(K:K).Find(...` without a `with` statement should work based on what I've read (but it does not in this module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following to LookIn:=xlFormulas per below.

```
Set cResult = .Find(What:=cSearch.Value, _
                   After:=cResult, _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _

Set cResult = .Find(What:=cSearch.Value, _
                       After:=cResult, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
```

When I do that it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `MATCH` instead of FIND.

Comment: Hi, If you could provide a code snap that solves the answer, that would be more helpful to the owner of the questions and others.